# Python BeautifulSoup writing 1 line in CSV

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the all the values of the product name, link and price shown on the page. Each taking up a row and separated by a comma.

I've written this code that works on a similar site, but for some reason here it only write the first result to the CSV.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

response = requests.get('https://www.micoca-cola.cl/bebidas/coca-cola')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find_all(class_='prateleira vitrine n12colunas')

with open('coca.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    headers = ['Producto', 'Link', 'Precio']
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)

    for item in items:
        producto = item.find(class_='product-block-name').get_text()
        link = item.find('a')['href']
        price = item.find(class_='bestPrice').get_text().replace('\n', '').replace('"', '').replace(' ', '')
        csv_writer.writerow([producto, link, price])
```

This gives the following result:
Producto,Link,Precio
"Refill 8 Coca-Cola Sin Azúcar retornable 2,0 lt. (No incluye envases)",https://www.micoca-cola.cl/refill-8-coca-cola-sin-azucar-retornable-20-lt-no-incluye-envases/p,"$9.520,00"

But there are other products on that page that I want to include on their own lines.

What's missing?

Comment: Did you try debigging it? How many items are in `items`?

Comment: Perhaps nothing is missing if the website only returned one row to your script, because data returned to your script is quite possibly different from what you happen to see in your browser.. You need to show that there is more data returned than your script is writing to CSV.

Comment: You only have one element in the webpage source with thst class name. Try checking a common locator for all the entries in the chrome  devtools. Replacing this locator with a common locator will result in listing all records in `items`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load all product titles, links and prices and saving to CSV, you can use this example:

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.micoca-cola.cl/bebidas/coca-cola'
html_doc = requests.get(url).text
page_url = 'https://www.micoca-cola.cl' + re.search(r"\.load\('(.*?)'", html_doc).group(1)

data = []
page = 1
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page_url + str(page)).content, 'html.parser')

    if not soup.body:
        break

    for product in soup.select('.product-group'):
        title = product.h4.text
        link = product.h4.a['href'] 
        print(title)
        print(link)
        price = product.find(class_="bestPrice")
        price = price.get_text(strip=True) if price else 'Out of Stock'
        print(price)
        print('-' * 80)

        data.append({
            'title': title,
            'link': link,
            'price': price
        })

    page += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
...
32                        Coca-Cola Light 6 x 591 ml.  ...    $ 5.340,00
33                       Coca-Cola Sin Azúcar 1,5 lt.  ...    $ 1.390,00
34                       Coca-Cola Sin Azúcar 2,5 lt.  ...    $ 1.890,00
35  Starter Kit Coca-Cola Light retornable 9 x 1,2...  ...   $ 10.710,00
36  Starter Kit Coca-Cola Original retornable 8 x ...  ...   $ 11.920,00
37                     Coca-Cola Original 6 x 3,0 lt.  ...   $ 13.140,00
38                Coca-Cola Energy Sin Azúcar 220 ml.  ...      $ 990,00
39  Starter Kit Coca-Cola Sin Azúcar retornable re...  ...    $ 1.490,00
40  Starter Kit Coca-Cola Sin Azúcar retornable 1,...  ...    $ 1.190,00
41                            Coca-Cola Light 2,5 lt.  ...    $ 1.890,00
42                            Coca-Cola Light 1,5 lt.  ...    $ 1.390,00
43                   Coca-Cola Sin Azúcar 6 x 250 ml.  ...    $ 2.290,00
44                         Coca-Cola Original 1,5 lt.  ...    $ 1.390,00
45                         Coca-Cola Original 3,0 lt.  ...    $ 2.190,00
46                     Coca-Cola Original 6 x 591 ml.  ...    $ 5.340,00
47  Starter Kit Coca-Cola Original retornable 9 x ...  ...   $ 10.710,00
48  Starter Kit Coca-Cola Light retornable 8 x 2,0...  ...   $ 11.920,00
49  Starter Kit Coca-Cola Original retornable 2,0 ...  ...    $ 1.490,00
50  Starter Kit Coca-Cola Light retornable retorna...  ...    $ 1.190,00
51                            Coca-Cola Light 3,0 lt.  ...    $ 2.190,00
52                     Coca-Cola Original 6 x 250 ml.  ...    $ 2.290,00
53  Starter Kit Coca-Cola Light retornable retorna...  ...    $ 1.490,00
54  Starter Kit Coca-Cola Original retornable 1,25...  ...    $ 1.190,00
55                         Coca-Cola Original 2,5 lt.  ...    $ 1.890,00
56                         Coca-Cola Original 1,0 lt.  ...      $ 990,00
57                            Coca-Cola Light 1,0 lt.  ...  Out of Stock

[58 rows x 3 columns]
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: This does completely solve my issue. It works perfectly.It's more advanced than my example so I'll try to get my head around it.